# What is fair usage of the "not an answer" deletion

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I answered a question in good faith.  The question was then put on hold and reworded by admins.  Within an hour of the rewording my answer was removed as "not an answer" (both have the same hours ago time stamp).  My answer was given in good faith and once the admins reworded the question I would have happily reworded my answer.

To add insult to injury on the same question there is an upvoted answer that:

1. Lists the processor to the product I recommended.
2. Has a "partial answer" comment from the same admin who removed mine.

In the cases of editing a question what is the fair usage of removing answers that attempted to answer the prior version but don't fit the rewording?  What is a reasonable amount of time to allow the writer to restructure their answer to fit the new wording?

Requested link: [How can I acquire free two-player D&D Basic/Expert adventures?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/41670/how-can-i-acquire-free-two-player-dd-basic-expert-adventures/41727#41727)

Comment: Just a heads up, you can edit it and flag it for undeletion.

Comment: I didn't know that so I will do so.  However, given I'm about to edit it nearly identical to an answer written after it was deleted I'm not sure what the point is.

Comment: Since it is not a race to who gets the points, but rather a race to give a complete answer to the querent, you can be happy someone else already gave it and leave your answer deleted. Less work for you. You're yust unlucky the question got edited, there will be other occasions to gain some reputation.

Comment: @Zachiel:It has nothing to do with points but fairness.  I answered a question in good faith (as did several other people).  The admins edited the question which changed the headline question significantly and then deleted all the existing answers.  When an answer that was identical to the first half of mine was posted the same admin who deleted my answer only commented that this one should be expanded.  You're right, it is less work for me but not bothering to answer at all and just coming here to slurp up answers without contributing is also easier.  Is your suggestion I freeload?

Comment: @Zachiel: I'd also argue the answer is less complete than mine as it refers to an earlier product with fewer tools than the free version of the production I mentioned (for example, the one I referred to includes a sample adventure using the material, the one allowed does not) so by deleting mine outright instead of giving me a heads up to edit the quality of available answers was lowered.

Comment: would be a good idea to link to the post in question.That gives more clarity to your situation.

Comment: Tangentially, *one* vote on a competing answer means nothing but that a single person liked it. Notably, that other answer is now downvoted more, underlining the insignificance of a single upvote on a competing answer early in its life. It's certainly noting to take as a personal slight by the whole site against your answer.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: The reason I pointed out the upvoted answer is the same person who deleted me as "not an answer" merely commented it was probably not an answer to that one even though we advised the same product, just different generations (Black versus Scarlet Heroes) which was a very large part of the confusion.  Had both been deleted or the deletion and comment by different individuals it would have made more sense.  Also, the original question was much broader than "I want free B/X starter adventures" and still retains the emphasis on 2 player which was explicitly the source of my answer.

Comment: You'll notice discrepancies like that sometimes. In this case, the admin involved is less likely to comment as firmly when something is up voted, because it suggests they might be wrong and the voter might be right, in the eyes of the community. In his case the caution didn't turn out to be necessary, but you'll still see it when there's that kind of doubt.

Comment: I just commented on that one while in the process of undeleting yours.  I can delete both if you'd prefer, I know I would.

Answer (score 5):

1. Neither your post nor the other are answering the question posed IMHO - before or after the edit. "I want free B/X starter adventures!" "Never mind that buy this other game." That makes the rest of this largely moot. I'm pretty sure I deleted your answer before BESW edited the post, even.
2. "Mods" did not edit the post, a high rep site user did. (Well, I did add some tags.) The whole community works together to improve questions and answers. If a question is incoherent and getting closed, consider waiting to answer - jumping to answer on a confusing question leads to this kind of thing happening.
3. Mods have lives outside this SE, so sometimes we don't respond for hours and sometimes we don't have time to write an essay on how to fix your answer. Yours was by no means the only answer I was having to delete and I needed to go to work.  Therefore "Doesn't answer the question." I think it was reasonably clear why right?
4. If an answer is deleted for cause, feel free and edit it to fit and flag for mod attention to be undeleted. Sorry if that costs rep in the meantime. We try to put sketchy questions on hold fast so that doesn't happen.

Comment: Re #1: timestamps confirm you did delete those answers a few minutes before the question got reframed.

Comment: "I think it was reasonable clear why right?".  No, because the original question asked for starter BX adventures for two players as well as free.  You fixated on the free and ignored the solo.  I pointed out something to help create solo adventures and that it had a free version.  Also, the other sections addressed the headline question which was how to get started.  Like you I also have a life and don't check the status of my answers every hour which is why when I logged in all I could see the question editing and deleting my answer both 15 hours prior and merely commenting on a similar one.

Comment: All operations here have timestamps on them if you want to understand more about what has happened. Anyway, sorry if this has been upsetting, but when people a) answer unclear questions and b) try to answer a question tangentially in can lead to issues with the answer.